# Win 10 Asus Laptop - after prolonged idle time Compatibility Telemetry kills the Hard Drive

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, telemetry

It's been a nightmare dealing with MTC on my new laptop... spend all my savings on a new machine and windows 10 keeps suffocating my hard drive with the MTC process.

What I find it doing is that it runs thru random software (like TeamViewer , antivirus, games , system volume information even...) and gets the hard drive to above 90% use for longer than 10 mins after each wake up I do.

I like to leave the laptop on idle (not in sleep mode), I just close the lid , I changed the power settings to NOT sleep when closing the lid, and just go out and do stuff but when I come back, it takes 15 mins or something until I get the chance to actually use the laptop for anything different than browsing the internet or opening files on windows explorer...

I have tried shutting down the process from task manager, ive tried disabling it from the Task Scheduler but it still comes back , and even worse is that killing it from task manager doesn't do any good, it keeps working on these random files.

Changing the antivirus software didnt help either... 
Anyone got any suggestions ?

Comment: I guess that under MTC you mean local network carrier. Is that right? What is the exact model of your Asus laptop? What are you msconfig settings? Add this information to your question.

Comment: MTC is Microsoft Telemetry Compatibility , but I swapped two of the words in the MCT


Asus K555L with i5-5200u gtx 940 m 6 gigs of ram 1 TB HDD